# Django App Deployment with Heroku: Error H10 App Crashed

Tags: django, heroku

I am trying to deploy a Django web app to Heroku, but whenever I try to open the app:

```
heroku open
```

I am greeted by:

```
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

on the site I am hosting it on.

I checked the logs, and they read:

```
2017-03-23T02:13:54.254184+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=salty-wildwood-65286.herokuapp.com request_id=64adedaf-b6e3-45f4-819d-32a24b1a029f fwd="xx.xxx.xxx.xxx" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Procfile

```
web: python manage.py runserver $PORT
```

the name of my app is immitweet, or at least, that's the name of the folder I initialized the GitHub repository.

I am able to run the app locally just fine, however it is when I try to deploy it and run it on the web is when I have this issue. I assume it has to do with the Procfile, but I do not know what.

Thanks!

(NOTE: This isn't a RoR application)

Comment: You should look for logs before that H10. Heroku tries booting your app, but for some reason the process stops itself. The error will be in your app logs.

Comment: When I did 'heroku logs --tail', I posted what I had received in the question above. I don't see anything to helpful there.

Comment: Fixed the issue by adding to my Procfile: web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT